# problems retrieving file extension in CI

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

How can I retrieve the file extension of an image while uploading?

I don't have any problems with the upload, just retrieving the **files extension** , which would be useful when creating thumbnails dynamically.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

```
$this->upload->data()
```

This is a helper function that returns an array containing all of the data related to the file you uploaded. Here is the array prototype:

```
Array
(
    [file_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [file_type]    => image/jpeg
    [file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
    [full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
    [raw_name]     => mypic
    [orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [client_name]  => mypic.jpg
    [file_ext]     => .jpg
    [file_size]    => 22.2
    [is_image]     => 1
    [image_width]  => 800
    [image_height] => 600
    [image_type]   => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
)
```

So after the user has uploaded something, you probably want to store the file extension in your database along with other details about the image :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
 $name_of_file_with_extn =  $this->upload->data('file_name')
```

you can change the item name from the below list

`file_name  Name of the file that was uploaded, including the filename extension
file_type   File MIME type identifier
file_path   Absolute server path to the file
full_path   Absolute server path, including the file name
raw_name    File name, without the extension
orig_name   Original file name. This is only useful if you use the encrypted name option.
client_name File name as supplied by the client user agent, prior to any file name preparation or incrementing
file_ext    Filename extension, period included
file_size   File size in kilobytes
is_image    Whether the file is an image or not. 1 = image. 0 = not.
image_width Image width
image_height    Image height
image_type  Image type (usually the file name extension without the period)
image_size_str  A string containing the width and height (useful to put into an image tag)`

This might help you.

Answer (score -1):

After you uploaded the file, you can get its property by:

```
$saved_file_name = $this->upload->data('file_name');
// will give you the filename along with the extension
```

If you want to get only the file extension before uploading it, use core PHP:

```
$file_ext = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

or to make it clean

```
$filename= $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$file_ext = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```