# PHP: How to get File Name & Extension of uploaded file in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i need to store only filename + extension of file when upload and rename done to my databse.my problem is can't get extension.

```
    $new_file_name=date("mdY")."_".time();
    $config['upload_path']          = './assets/images/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 2048;
    $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768;
    $config['file_name']            = $new_file_name;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('uploadFile'))
    {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            var_dump($error);
    }
    else
    {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            var_dump($data);
            echo $config['file_name'] . $config['file_ext'];

    }
```

my next question load helper form for ? or need load form to use library form_validation ?

```
$this->load->helper(array('form')); for ?

$this->load->library('form_validation'); this for validation rule
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract a file extension in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php)

Comment: Refer this user guide : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#preferences And apply using this answer . : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5257466/4952944

Comment: You should be seeing all the File attributes from your var_dump($data) which you created from the $this->upload->data(). So you just need to grab what you want from that.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw it work now echo $config['file_name'] . $this->upload->data('file_ext');

Comment: Good stuff :), you were this close!

Comment: @TimBrownlaw u remind me this is fullname & ext : echo $this->upload->data('orig_name'); 0000_00000.jpg hehehe

Comment: Even better. Now you are cooking!

Answer (score 6):

**custom upload filename codeigniter** 
first you can to explode with (.) in filename, then you get array, then catch the end array with function end().
and last i can to join filename with this date.

```php
$dname = explode(".", $_FILES['gambar']['name']);
$ext = end($dname);
$_FILES['gambar']['name'] = strtolower('fitur_h_'.date('YmdHis').'.'.$ext);

//fitur_h_20200120143157.png  //output filename
```

i hope my answer can help you

Answer (score 2):

After you uploaded the file, you can get its property by:

```
$saved_file_name = $this->upload->data('file_name');
// will give you the filename along with the extension
```

If you want to get the file extension before uploading it, use core php:

```
$file_ext = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

or to make it clean

```
$filename= $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$file_ext = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the below code for image name with extension on post to solve issue,

```
$config['file_name'].$this->upload->data('file_ext')
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too late, still I'm giving the answer.

If you want to get the image extension, then use pathinfo function with PATHINFO_EXTENSION parameter.
eg.

```
$imageExtention = pathinfo($_FILES["image"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
echo imageExtention;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and i just figured it out.

I was trying to get the name with this: $this->upload->data('file_name');
but it was always empty, and i just finded out that you need to set something before you can access the data() array.

When your code successfully uploads the file, type this: `$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());`

after that, all the data() indexes will be accessible, 'file_name' included. The list with all indexes is in the documentation: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#preferences

ps: I know it's been 2 years since this post but maybe someone can find it helpful if they stuck with this too.

Answer (score -3):

you can get file name using this code

```
$file_name = $data['file_name'];
echo $file_name;
```

and extension for file

```
$ext = implode('.',$file_name);
echo $ext[1];
```

Comment: it is explode not implode

Comment: and it won't work if file name has "."(dot). for example: abc.xyz.jpg